# Examples of continuous integer-valued functions on totally disconnected spaces

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I wanted to see examples of continuous integer-valued functions $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ on a totally disconnected space $X.$ I have only some abstract examples in mind.

Comment: Well, every function defined on a discrete space is continuous. But that is rather trivial answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can take $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$, given by $f(n)=n$.